# Problema com classe de alteração de dados

Tags: java, mysql

Estou tentando alterar dados do meu BD via aplicação Java, porém quando executo o código a seguir recebo o erro 
***(You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Editar' at line 1).***

```
jButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("actionPerformed()"); // TODO Auto-generated Event stub actionPerformed()
                salvaDados();
                String Editar = ("update livros set ISBN='"+isbn+"',"+"titulo_livro='"+titulo+"',"+"autor_livro='"+autor+"',"+"editora_livro='"+editora+"',"+"consignacao='"+consignacao+"',"+"preco='"+preco+"',"+"quantidade='"+quantidade+"' where ISBN='"+Index.cod_ISBN+"'");
                try {
                    Edita.stm.executeUpdate("Editar");
                    Edita.stm.close();
                    Edita.Executar("select * from livros where ISBN='"+Index.cod_ISBN+"'");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Alteração de registro efetuada!");
                    Index.atualizaTabela();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Index.atualizaTabela();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Não foi possível efetuar a alteração do registro!");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

}

private void salvaDados() {
                isbn = jTextField.getText().toString();
                titulo = jTextField1.getText().toString();
                autor = jTextField2.getText().toString();
                editora = jTextField3.getText().toString();
                consignacao = jTextField6.getText().toString();
                preco = jTextField4.getText().toString();
                quantidade = jTextField5.getText().toString();

if (isbn == null || titulo == null || autor == null || editora == null || consignacao == null || preco == null || quantidade == null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Certifique-se de que nenhum campo de texto está em branco antes de salvar!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trecho abaixo retirado do seu código você está utilizando uma String como argumento e não a variável do tipo String. Veja:

```
String Editar = ("update livros set ISBN='"+isbn+"',"+"titulo_livro='"+titulo+"',"+"autor_livro='"+autor+"',"+"editora_livro='"+editora+"',"+"consignacao='"+consignacao+"',"+"preco='"+preco+"',"+"quantidade='"+quantidade+"' where ISBN='"+Index.cod_ISBN+"'");
                try {
                    **Edita.stm.executeUpdate("Editar");**
                    Edita.stm.close();
                    Edita.Executar("select * from livros where ISBN='"+Index.cod_ISBN+"'");
```

Altere a linha destacada para:

```
    Edita.stm.executeUpdate(Editar);
```

Observação: por uma questão de convenção, opte por começar o nome de uma variável com letra minuscula.

Comment: a linha destacada que me refiro é a linha que coloquei asteriscos (**)

Comment: era exatamente isso. Nem sei como deixei passar